# Recursively aggregate duplicates in a keyed pair of lists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two lists, *where items between lists at matching indexes are linked*. The first list provides keys that tie to the second lists values:

```
List<Double> a1 = [10,20,20,30,10];           // keys
List<Double> y1 = [2012,2013,2012,2012,2013]; // values
```

I want to remove duplicates from the key (index) list in such a way that when a duplicate is found, the value of the key is added. So for example, if two keys were found with the value 10, I want to replace both keys with a single key of value 20. This process would be repeated until there were no duplicate keys remaining. So I want the output of the lists like this:

```
List<Double> a1 = [60,30];
List<Double> y1 = [2012,2013];
```

I have attempted to solve this problem using the following code, but the output is not correct.

```
y2=new ArrayList<Double>();
a2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
String y = "";
double a = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < y1.size(); i++) {

    if (y1.get(i).equals(y)) {
        a = a + y1.get(i);
    } else {
        if (!y.equals("")) {
            y2.add(y);
            a2.add(a);
        }

        y = y1.get(i);
        a = a1.get(i);
    }
}

y2.add(y);
a2.add(a);
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Just dump the elements from List into the Set, it will take out duplicates.

Comment: Use a `Map<Double, Double>`.

Comment: use a map, add to value if a key exists

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `Map`

```
Map<Double, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < y1.size(); i++) {
    double oldValue = map.containsKey(y1.get(i)) ? map.get(y1.get(i)) : 0.0;

    map.put(y1.get(i), oldValue + a1.get(i));
}

y1.clear();
a1.clear();

for (Entry<Double, Double> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    y1.add(entry.getKey());
    a1.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: You should add code to put values in the map back to the lists, as is required by question. Also, `TreeMap` might be more appropriate, to get lists in sorted order easily.

Comment: @hyde put the data back in the lists now

Comment: I suggest y1.addAll(map.keySet());
 a1.addAll(map.values()); instead of for-loop.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi I wasn't sure if the order of elements in both sets is guaranteed to be the same...

Answer (score 0):

```
private void method(List<Double> y1, List<Double> a1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < y1.size(); i++) {
        if (y1.get(i) != -1) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < y1.size(); j++) {
            if (y1.get(i).equals(y1.get(j))) {
            y1.set(j, -1d);
            a1.set(i, a1.get(i) + a1.get(j));
            a1.set(j, -1d);
            }
        }
        }
    }
    for (Iterator<Double> itr = y1.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
        if (itr.next().equals(-1d))
        itr.remove();
    for (Iterator<Double> itr = a1.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
        if (itr.next().equals(-1d))
        itr.remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because the y1 array is not ordered. As you want to preserve the mapping between y1 and a1 you should create a class with this values, and create an array of this class:

```
public class Elem implements Comparable<Elem> 
{
    double year;
    double value;

// getters and setters 

public double getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(double value) {
    this.value = value;
}


public int compareTo(Elem item) 
    {
        if (this.getYear() == item.getYear())
        return 0;
    else if (this.getYear() > item.getYear())
        return 1;
    else 
        return -1;
}

public int hashCode()
{
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    buffer.append(this.year);
    buffer.append(this.value);
    return buffer.toString().hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object item)
{
    if (item instanceof Elem)
    {
        Elem e = (Elem) item;
        if (e.getYear() == this.getYear())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Now you can crate the array, pupulate and sort it:

```
    List<Elem> y1 = new ArrayList<Elem>();

    //---- populate array ----

    Collections.sort(y1);

    ArrayList<Elem> y2;

    y2 = new ArrayList<Elem>();
    Elem y = null;

    double a = 0;

    for(int i = 0;i<y1.size();i++){
        if((y != null) && (y1.get(i).equals(y))){
            a = y.getValue() + y1.get(i).getValue();
            y1.get(i).setValue(a);
            y = y1.get(i);
        }
        else{
            if(y != null) {
                y2.add(y);
            }

            y = y1.get(i);
        }


    }
    if(y != null) {
        y2.add(y);
    }
```